# Trouble getting all the groups that belong to a PC

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi I am having trouble pulling all of the groups from our AD environment.
It seems to be only pulling the Administrators group although I haven't set any parameters for $LocalGroupName. My end goal is to pull all users and groups that belong to a PC in our domain.

This is what I have:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(    ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
            )]
[string[]]
$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,

[Parameter()]
[string]
$OutputDir = "c:\temp"
)

 Begin {

 $OutputFile = Join-Path $OutputDir "LocalGroupMembers.csv"
 Write-Verbose "Script will write the output to $OutputFile folder"
 Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "ComputerName, LocalGroupName, Status, MemberType, 
MemberDomain, MemberName"
}

 Process {
  ForEach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    Write-host "Working on $Computer"
    If(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Verbose "$Computer is offline. Proceeding with next computer"
        Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,$LocalGroupName,Offline"
        Continue
    } else {
        Write-Verbose "Working on $computer"
        try {
            $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$LocalGroupName"
            $members = @($group.Invoke("Members"))
            Write-Verbose "Successfully queries the members of $computer"
            if(!$members) {
                Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value 
   "$Computer,$LocalGroupName,NoMembersFound"
                Write-Verbose "No members found in the group"
                continue
            }
        }        
        catch {
            Write-Verbose "Failed to query the members of $computer"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,,FailedToQuery"
            Continue
        }
        foreach($member in $members) {
            try {
                $MemberName = 
   $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                $MemberType = 
   $member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                $MemberPath = 
   $member.GetType().Invokemember("ADSPath","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                $MemberDomain = $null
                if($MemberPath -match "^Winnt\:\/\/(?<domainName>\S+)\/(?<CompName>\S+)\/") {
                    if($MemberType -eq "User") {
                        $MemberType = "LocalUser"
                    } elseif($MemberType -eq "Group"){
                        $MemberType = "LocalGroup"
                    }
                    $MemberDomain = $matches["CompName"]

                } elseif($MemberPath -match "^WinNT\:\/\/(?<domainname>\S+)/") {
                    if($MemberType -eq "User") {
                        $MemberType = "DomainUser"
                    } elseif($MemberType -eq "Group"){
                        $MemberType = "DomainGroup"
                    }
                    $MemberDomain = $matches["domainname"]

                } else {
                    $MemberType = "Unknown"
                    $MemberDomain = "Unknown"
                }
            Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "$Computer, $LocalGroupName, SUCCESS, 
    $MemberType, $MemberDomain, $MemberName"
            } catch {
                Write-Verbose "failed to query details of a member. Details $_"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,,FailedQueryMember"
            }

        } 
    }

}

}
End {}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You say you're "pulling all of the groups from our AD environment", but that code is only reading the local groups on a computer. That code also seems overly complicated for what it's doing. Did you write that, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, yeah its pulling the local groups from the PCs in our domain. I got this script online

Comment: `([adsi]"WinNT://$servername,computer").Children.Find('groupnamehere', 'group').Members().ForEach([adsi])` should be a lot simpler

Comment: You could use `Get-LocalGroup` and `Get-LocalGroupMember` which is far more simple for this, why not use them?

Comment: Can you point me out on how i can use it with this script, sorry im new to powershell.
I just want it to pull all the local groups and users that are on all the machines in my environment. Currently its only pulling the "Administrators" group only.